# PyOpenGL correct syntax for setting up array of type GLfloat

Tags: arrays, pyopengl

I'm trying to set up an array of 3D co-ordinates of type GLfloat but can only find reference to setting up a single variable of that type,

```
a = GLfloat(1.0)
```

I have tried,

```
a = GLfloat([0.0, 0.0, 0.0],[1.0, 1.0, 1.0],[2.0, 2.0, 2.0])
```

but get the following error,

*TypeError: **init** expected at most 1 arguments, got 3*

In C is easy,

```
Glfloat a[3][3] = {{0.0, 0.0, 0.0},{1.0, 1.0, 1.0},{2.0, 2.0, 2.0}}
```

So how do I do that in Python?

Answer (score 2):

you could get an array of glfloats with a list comprehension

```
pythonarray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7, 8]
glfloatarray = [GLfloat(x) for x in pythonarray]
```

But you're probably bettor off using pyopengls [array extension](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/tutorials/shader_1.html) possibly in combination with [numpy float arrays](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/numeric_arrays.html). This allows you to easily create vbos of your data.

Comment: Thanks I've gone with using a numpy.array of floats, no problems so far.